# I am setting up aws config from cloudformation template but facing error in the Policy, even though i used the steps mentioned in Doc

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

```
IamRoleForConfig:
    Type: 'AWS::IAM::Role'
    Properties:      
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
          - Sid: 'Allow Config to record resources'
            Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - config.amazonaws.com
            Action:
              - sts:AssumeRole
      Path: /
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWS_ConfigRole
```

Comment: What is the error? What Doc?

Comment: Thank you for reverting @marcin. I figured it out. Config delivery channel needs access to s3 bucket to write configuration data. I was missing it. After granting access to s3 bucket it worked